# $\theta$ distribution

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

reading number theory texts in one part I found myself "assuming that the prime numbers have distribution $\theta > 1/2$..."

what does this refer to?
Does it have to do with the density given by the prime number theorem?

Comment: I'm guessing it means that the [Bombieri–Vinogradov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombieri–Vinogradov_theorem#Statement_of_the_Bombieri–Vinogradov_theorem) holds for $Q=x^\theta$.

Comment: You found this in more than one text, Luis? and with no explanation? Could you tell us which texts, and which pages, please?

Comment: In the proof to maynard theorem,use a lot of sentences "Assume that the primes have level of distribution $\theta$..."

Comment: I don't know if you mean Bombieri-Vinogradov theorem or Elliott-Halberstam conjecture ,

Comment: or is there some kind of distribution $\theta$ ?

Comment: Lack of context, many ways to approach "the distribution of prime numbers".

Comment: Please, Luis: give the bibliographic information for "the proof to maynard theorem", or a link to the proof, so we can see the context.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted yesterday, Luis?

Comment: Are you still here, Luis?

Answer (score 1):

On the second page of https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/Maynard.pdf it says,

Given $\theta>0$, we say the primes have level of distribution $\theta$ if, for every $A>0$, we have $$\sum_{q\le x^{\theta}}\max_{(a,q)=1}\left|\pi(x;q,a)-{\pi(x)\over\phi(q)}\right|\ll_A{x\over(\log x)^A}$$

In a footnote it says, "different authors have given slightly different names or definitions to this concept."